# How to set "SELECT" option as first option in wpf comboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I am using Enum Logic to populate the comboBox. The comboBox is populated correctly. But I want to set "--SELECT--" as the first option.

How can It be done??

Comment: please post some code..what have u done till now?

Comment: @Yamini please put some code that you have tried yourself and then we will suggest modification or enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your xaml combobox

```
SelectedIndex="0"
```

Comment: that will select the first item of the list. right?

Comment: and for adding  --Select-- you can append the first item as --Select--

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your list before sending it to the view:

```
 public List<string> YourList 
    {
        get
        {
             if (_list[0] != "--Select--")
                _list = _list.Insert(0, "--Select--");
             return _list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the list is not of string type. Its of some class type

Comment: So create a new instance of your object with defaults value

Answer (score 0):

Try setting null value

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="displayText" Text="{Binding}" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="displayText" Property="Text" Value="--Select--" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

And VM:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                null,"1","2","3"
            };

        }
    }

    public string Item { get; set; }
```

Comment: <Setter TargetName="displayText" Property="Text" Value="--Select--" />

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to make `ComboBox` editable so that you can set custom text, and readonly so that items can only be selected:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="--SELECT--" />
```

Note that this will change the look of a control, so if that is a problem for you, you will have to use more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your Class has a Property you want to display in the ComboBox take a look at following approach:

Set a namespace to your class:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Company.ProjectName.Models;assembly=Company.ProjectName.Models"
```

Then in your ComboBox add a new Item of your class like this:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding BindingProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" >
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <models:CustomClass Name="--SELECT--" ID="0"/>
         <!--<ComboBoxItem Background="LightGray" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Height="1" Margin="7,0,7,0" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False"/> !-->
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ObservableCollection}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add the value(--SELECT--)to the data-table after retrieving data from database and set the selected index to 0.

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["DATA"] = "--SELECT--";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

after binding`combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`